# MySQLにパスワード無しでログインできてしまうのはなぜ？

Tags: mysql, centos, mariadb

OS: CentOS
DB: MariaDB

サーバーのコンソールから`mysql`と入力するだけで、MySQL (MariaDB) にログインできてしまいます。

`mysql -u root -p` のようにユーザー名とパスワードの入力をしないと、ログインできないようにしたいです。

---

```
MariaDB [(none)]> set password = password('aaaaaaaa');
MariaDB [(none)]> select user, host, password from mysql.user;
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| User        | Host      | Password                                  |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| mariadb.sys | localhost |                                           |
| root        | localhost | *30F3C7028E075C74CDDCBA2FBA415FCE0306793E |
| mysql       | localhost | invalid                                   |
+-------------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` を実行しても `systemctl restart mysql` で MySQL のサービスを再起動しても状況は変わらずです。

```
MariaDB [(none)]> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.3-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:          6
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server:                 MariaDB
Server version:         10.6.3-MariaDB MariaDB Server
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8mb3
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb3
UNIX socket:            /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Uptime:                 1 min 40 sec
```

`-u`と`-p`オプションなしの`mysql`コマンドだけでログインし、`status`で確認したとき、`Current user`は`root@localhost`となっています。

また、`mysql -u root -p`でログインするとき、パスワードを空欄にしたり、パスワードにでたらめな文字列を入力した場合でもエラーとならずにログインできてしまいます。

CentOS側のユーザーが`root`のときにこの現象が発生します。

CentOS側のユーザーを`taro`のような一般ユーザーに切り替えた場合、`mysql`でログインしようとすると`ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'taro'@'localhost'`のような表示になります。

MySQLへのログインで、ユーザー名とパスワードの入力を必須にするにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: [Mysql (MariaDB 10.0.29): Set root password, but still can login without asking password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44298160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 回答

次の方法を調べてみてください。

1. `mysql_secure_installation` を調べてみる
2. 次のSQLを調べてみる

   ```
   ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' identified BY 'XXXX';
   ```

---

MySQLのバージョンによって、パスワードの設定方法に違いがあるようです。
新しいバージョンではALTER USERを使うようですが、私は使ったことがありません。

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' identified BY 'XXXX';
```

私は `mysql_secure_installation` コマンドを使って、MySQLのrootユーザのパスワードを設定しています。
MySQLのインストール直後に実行しているので、既にユーザやテーブルを作成してあるときの影響は分かりません。

Comment: `ALTER USER`でパスワードを再設定したら現象が改善されました。

Comment: 現象が改善されてよかったです。新規にMySQL(MariaDB)をインストールしたときはmysql_secure_installationを実行することをおすすめします。mysql_secure_installationの中でバージョンの差異を吸収してくれるようです。

Answer (score 0):

うちのNASにmariadb をインストールしてみたところ、次のようになりました。

```
MariaDB [mysql]> select user,host,password from user;
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| user | host      | password                                  |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
| root | localhost | *4ACFE3202A5FF5CF467898FC58AAB1D615029441 |
| root | agartha   |                                           |
| root | 127.0.0.1 |                                           |
| root | ::1       |                                           |
|      | localhost |                                           |
|      | agartha   |                                           |
+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [mysql]>
```

このように、ユーザー名、パスワードが空白のUSERがいるので、mysqlコマンドだけでDBにはいれるようになっているはずです。

なので、mysql.userからパスワードが’’となっているユーザーを削除し、データベースを再起動すればmysqlコマンドのみでログインは出来なくなるはずです

Comment: ユーザー名とパスワードが空白のユーザーは削除済みです。